# Windows SBS 2008 user unable to RDP in even though it is in the correct groups

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, rdp, windows-terminal-services

**Problem:**
A user was accidentally deleted from a Windows SBS 2008 server running Active Directory and we have been unable to grant it RDP rights - the error message states that the account needs to be granted 'Logon through Terminal Services Rights'.

**Setup:**
A single Windows 2008 SBS server running hyper-VM with a single VM on it that handles the TS licenses

**Attempted fixes/more info:**

Things we have attempted to do to fix the problem (all done via Active Directory Users and Computers)

- Added it to the Administrators and Remote Desktop Users groups
- Added it to the Remote Desktop Users group on the VM (the account can
  now log into the VM at least)
- Cloned an existing account on the main server

None of these seemed to have solved the problem. There is currently 2 free TS licenses so I don't believe that it is a licensing issue.

It's almost as if there is a higher group policy setting or similar that is overriding the groups that the user is added to, but I am not sure where to look from here.

I've already made sure that the user don't have TS access disabled in it's user settings

Any suggestions? (Unfortunately, I'm a Linux admin so I've limited experience with Windows systems)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to delete the user account and recreate it via the SBS console, not ADUC.

Creating the user account in ADUC is not going to add the user to the appropriate SBS user role and it's also not going to set any of the other options that are set via the SBS console, such as mailbox quotas, remote access, etc.

Comment: I have deleted and re-added the account via the SBS console and added it to the admin and RDP groups (on the dedicated and the VM), unfortunately that hasn't solved the issue :(